# Query to combine value of another column value in insert command of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm really sorry if you don't understand my question, my english is not good .
kindly correct it if can

I create a table  called  'Class'

```
create table class(
    candidate_id int identity,
    candidate_name varchar(50),
    candidate_course varchar(15) default 'SQL Server');
```

I just want to insert only **candidate_name column**

```
  Insert into class(Candidate_name)
   values('User');
```

If I execute this command i'll get

| Candidate_id | Candidate_name | Candidate_course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | SQL Server |

As, identity column will generate no.s so is it possible combine both with candidate_name while inserting .

Just like other languages Print("Hello world "+S) where s='Stack' output would be

> Hello world Stack

Expecting output like this

| Candidate_id | Candidate_name | Candidate_course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | SQL Server |
| 2 | user2 | SQL Server |
| 3 | user3 | SQL Server |
| nth | user nth | SQL Server |

kindly help . Hope i'm clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to concatenate an identity with a user defined value provided in a raw insert statement. That being said there are a couple of things that you can do.

## Define the table with a generated column.

You can actually define a column in your table that is generated from other columns.

```
create table class(
    candidate_id int identity,
    candidate_name varchar(50),
    candidate_course varchar(15) default 'SQL Server',
    candidate_name_id AS CONCAT(candidate_name, '_', candidate_id)
    );



Insert into class(Candidate_name)
   VALUES
   ('User'),
   ('User'),
   ('User');


SELECT *
FROM dbo.class AS c
```

This produces the following table.

| candidate_id | candidate_name | candidate_course | candidate_name_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User | SQL Server | User_1 |
| 2 | User | SQL Server | User_2 |
| 3 | User | SQL Server | User_3 |

For further reference on 'Computed Columns'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16

## Define The Table With A Sequence

Instead of using an identity you can use a sequence which gives you a lot more flexibility. You can generate the next value for the sequence and use it in your insert statements. I actually recommend this since you can generate the sequence before hand and use it in other parts of your code.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_class INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 AS INT;

create table class(
    candidate_id int DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class,
    candidate_name varchar(50),
    candidate_course varchar(15) default 'SQL Server'
    );



Insert into class(candidate_id, Candidate_name)
   VALUES
   (NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class, CONCAT('User', '_', NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class)),
   (NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class, CONCAT('User', '_', NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class)),
   (NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class, CONCAT('User', '_', NEXT VALUE FOR SQ_class));


SELECT *
FROM dbo.class AS c
```

Which gives you the following result

| candidate_id | candidate_name | candidate_course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User_1 | SQL Server |
| 2 | User_2 | SQL Server |
| 3 | User_3 | SQL Server |

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate those 2 values simply using '+'.
Also, we need to convert the candidate_id to varchar, since it is integer.

**Query**

```
select candidate_id,
Candiate_name + cast(candidate_id as varchar(10)) as candidate_name,
Candidate_course
From class;
```

Comment: thanks i got output as shown , but is it possible to concatenate  while at **inserting**

Comment: You can create computed columns

Answer (score 0):

in the same column you can achieve that, and as the other answer shows you can generate it on every sele as it is redundat, to have another column.

But you can make a generated column

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table class(
    candidate_id int identity,
    candidate_name varchar(50),
    fnew_candidate AS (candidate_name + cast(candidate_id as varchar(10))) PERSISTED,
    candidate_course varchar(15) default 'SQL Server');


  Insert into class(Candidate_name)
   values('User');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0529ea/1)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM class
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0529ea/1/0)**:

```
| candidate_id | candidate_name | fnew_candidate | candidate_course |
|--------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
|            1 |           User |          User1 |       SQL Server |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Trigger` to update the inserted `candidate_name` automatically as the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ClassInsert ON Class
    FOR INSERT AS 
    Begin
        Update Class Set candidate_name = (candidate_name + Cast(candidate_id as nvarchar(5)))
        Where candidate_id = (Select Max(candidate_id) From Class);
    End
```

See a demo from ***[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=84d0e6deb73f3e045f83e5551cc9acdb)***.

Comment: That's a decent solution as well, but you would want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to ensure that you get the correct identity.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16